# Same AppId for multiple URLs

Tags: google-cast

I submitted a whitelist request and included two URLs (e.g. `http://myserver/test1.html` and `http://myserver/test2.html`) so I could test a couple of different things from the same server. I got my whitelist response back, but what confused me is that the response showed the same App ID mapped to both URLs. I was thinking that there was a one-to-one mapping between App ID and the main URL of the application, but apparently I am wrong.

So if the same app ID can map to different URLs, how do I differentiate between the test1 and test2 apps when starting them?

Comment: I wonder if they expect the receivers to be in their own folders.  This is how I did it, and they gave me 2 id's.  The second with the _1 at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was a bug on their end. I received emails overnight informing me that:

> There was a problem during the initial registration of one of your applications which has been resolved, but required an update to the App ID.

They issued me new app IDs which differ by the addition of the "_1"

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain they are 100% the same.

The second one should have an "_1" at the end of it.

So they may look the same, but are actually slightly different strings.

Comment: No, I am certain that they are exactly the same. I have checked them over and over again thinking that they were different in one character and I was somehow overlooking the difference. I even went to the extra step of pasting the app ID from each line of the email into a separate file and doing a file compare and it tells me they are the same. There is no "_1" at the end of either

Comment: Have you tried using your app ID with a _1 after it to see if it they just forgot to add it in the email they sent you?

Comment: You can copy one AppID and do a search for it. If you find next one, they are identical AppID. You don't need to do a file comparison.